# API in Flask--returns JSON but HTML exceptions break my JSON client

Tags: python, html, json, api, flask

exceptions returned in HTML break my JSON client. I want to jsonify this output.

More detail: i have a view function which an endpoint of this api app.

As you can see, this function returns the result in json.

```
@app.route('/route1')
def api_route1():
    if user_id in request.args: 
        k1 = request.args['user_id']
        return flask.jsonify(recs=some_function(k1))
    else:
        return "no valid user_id supplied"
```

The problem, unhandled exception are in HTML, e.g.,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css" 
            type="text/css">
```

This breaks my json client. The HTML format is clearly a default, but i don't know how to opt out of it and specify jsonified exceptions (and ideally jsonify anything returned even headers).

I suspect what i need is somewhere in the excellent Flask documentation, but i can't find it.

Comment: So you're trying to preserve the error messages and send them as JSON in case something goes wrong?

Comment: @Blender, yep, that's what i want.

Answer (score 23):

You should define HTTP [error handlers in flask.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/)

A simple JSON returing 404 handler might look something like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return flask.jsonify(error=404, text=str(e)), 404
```

With this you will be able to check for `data.error` on the client and if it exists you can get the error text with data.text (the error passed as `e` is `werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound` whose string representation is "404: Not Found").

Comment: Does this mean I need to create an error handler per non-success http status code (5xx and 4xx)? There must be a better way.

Answer (score 7):

Making the traceback available to the JSON client has the potential to disclose sensitive information.

My advice is:

- turn debug off
- install a log aggregation tool like [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry)
- make the error 500 page for this application return a generic error in json format

The 500 page could look like:

```
{ "error": "500 - internal server error" }
```

Comment: This is what the OP should do.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should do the trick. So the idea is to catch any exception that might have been raised, get the exception details formatted as a string using the traceback module and then return that as valid json. I would recommend putting a bunch of except statements with the main types of errors you expect to happen and a more readable error message. Then you can have one last except as a catch all in case something strange and unexpected happens.

```
import traceback

@app.route('/route1')
def api_route1():
    if user_id in request.args: 
        try:
            k1 = request.args['user_id']
            return flask.jsonify(recs=some_function(k1))
        except:
            return flask.jsonify(exception=traceback.format_exc())
    else:
        return flask.jsonify(exception="no valid user_id supplied")
```

Comment: even the else part can have jsonify, this will again return html when user_id is not in arguments.

Comment: @Codeanu good suggestion, I updated the answer with what you suggested.